# W10 keeps denying access to its files from the Ubuntu side

Tags: permissions

Any work around this? Everytime I want access to a file on Files to the w10 side I get an error message. Same with Rhythmbox: missing files.

Still running into trouble. Partial and bumd solution was to:
open files
open my w10 folder

after that I get access to Windows files and folders, which looks like a BUG to me.

Adding a screenshot as requested:

[image]

Comment: Edit the question and attach a photo or the error message in the question.

Comment: Where is this Win10 folder? Are you trying to access some bookmarked locations inside a partition without mounting it first? Have you tried setting automount for that partition?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the partitions are mounted first. A solution would be to remount them as such:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,exec /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever
```

Comment: didnt work. Thanks anyways